# how to know clients browser is on trusted zone or not by javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on site which have a lot of configuration and security settings and I have to check either clients browser is on trusted zone or not using JavaScript.Is it possible to determine whether my web site is being accessed as a trusted site? The reason I'd like to do this is that some functions won't work unless the site is being accessed as a trusted site, and I'd like to be able to warn users.
is there any solution ?

Comment: What trusted zone are you talking about? The thing that old IE browsers had?

Answer (score 0):

No can do, sorry - this data is not accessible to the webpages (and for good reason).

You might get away with an ActiveX control checking this, but that has its own bag of issues.

Worst case, you could make a *guess* - try something that's forbidden in the Internet Zone (e.g. URLACTION_ACTIVEX_SCRIPTLET_RUN ) by default, and see if it succeeds.

Note however, that the concept of "zones" is IE-specific, and it may not even be very useful in its new versions (IE9?).